# Drag and Drop TextView anywhere

Tags: android, textview

I want to move `TextView` on the `ImageView`, but I cant move it even though I use the code which is in the Google Developer page.
How I drag and drop a `TextView` **anywhere on screen** in Android?

Comment: Add the code of what you have already tried - also if in trying to move the TextView you get errors, include those as well in your question to enable the community to help; Check out the [Quick Tour of StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for tips on asking good questions, etc.

Comment: The code on the Google Developer Page works... The only way for us to help, is to see your code, and explain what you're doing differently

Comment: No its not working.. It contains errors

Answer (score 1):

XML FILE:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Test1" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Test2" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA FILE

```
    public class TestActivity extends Activity {

        int pressed_x,pressed_y,pressed_x1,pressed_y1;
        TextView tv1,tv2;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

             tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
             tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);

             tv1.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListenerTv1);
             tv2.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListenerTv2);
        }

        public final View.OnTouchListener mOnTouchListenerTv1 = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv1.getLayoutParams();


                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.d("TAG","@@@@ TV1 ACTION_UP");
                        // Where the user started the drag
                        pressed_x = (int) event.getRawX();
                        pressed_y = (int) event.getRawY();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Log.d("TAG","@@@@ TV1 ACTION_UP");
                        // Where the user's finger is during the drag
                        final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                        final int y = (int) event.getRawY();

                        // Calculate change in x and change in y
                        int dx = x - pressed_x;
                        int dy = y - pressed_y;

                        // Update the margins
                        relativeLayoutParams.leftMargin += dx;
                        relativeLayoutParams.topMargin += dy;
                        tv1.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);

                        // Save where the user's finger was for the next ACTION_MOVE
                        pressed_x = x;
                        pressed_y = y;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.d("TAG","@@@@ TV1 ACTION_UP");

                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        };
        public final View.OnTouchListener mOnTouchListenerTv2 = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv2.getLayoutParams();

                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.d("TAG","@@@@ TV2 ACTION_DOWN");
                        // Where the user started the drag
                        pressed_x1 = (int) event.getRawX();
                        pressed_y1 = (int) event.getRawY();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Log.d("TAG","@@@@ TV2 ACTION_MOVE");
                        // Where the user's finger is during the drag
                        final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                        final int y = (int) event.getRawY();

                        // Calculate change in x and change in y
                        int dx = x - pressed_x1;
                        int dy = y - pressed_y1;

                        // Update the margins
                        relativeLayoutParams1.leftMargin += dx;
                        relativeLayoutParams1.topMargin += dy;
                        tv2.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams1);

                        // Save where the user's finger was for the next ACTION_MOVE
                        pressed_x1 = x;
                        pressed_y1 = y;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.d("TAG","@@@@ TV2 ACTION_UP");
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Its working when I use single TextView but its not working when I use more than a TextView(When I touch tv1 after moving or touching tv2,every time tv1 is moving eventhough I try to move tv2).

Comment: Ya Its working but I want to rearrange the views check my code below its not working when I give centerInParent="true". could you please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linear"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Test1" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Test2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int pressed_x,pressed_y,pressed_x1,pressed_y1;
TextView tv1,tv2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);

    tv1.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListenerTv1);
    tv2.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListenerTv2);
}

public final View.OnTouchListener mOnTouchListenerTv1 = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv1.getLayoutParams();


        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.d("TAG","@@@@ TV1 ACTION_UP");
                // Where the user started the drag
                pressed_x = (int) event.getRawX();
                pressed_y = (int) event.getRawY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.d("TAG","@@@@ TV1 ACTION_UP");
                // Where the user's finger is during the drag
                final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int y = (int) event.getRawY();

                // Calculate change in x and change in y
                int dx = x - pressed_x;
                int dy = y - pressed_y;

                // Update the margins
                relativeLayoutParams.leftMargin += dx;
                relativeLayoutParams.topMargin += dy;
                tv1.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);

                // Save where the user's finger was for the next ACTION_MOVE
                pressed_x = x;
                pressed_y = y;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.d("TAG","@@@@ TV1 ACTION_UP");

                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
};
public final View.OnTouchListener mOnTouchListenerTv2 = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv2.getLayoutParams();

        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.d("TAG","@@@@ TV2 ACTION_DOWN");
                // Where the user started the drag
                pressed_x1 = (int) event.getRawX();
                pressed_y1 = (int) event.getRawY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.d("TAG","@@@@ TV2 ACTION_MOVE");
                // Where the user's finger is during the drag
                final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int y = (int) event.getRawY();

                // Calculate change in x and change in y
                int dx = x - pressed_x1;
                int dy = y - pressed_y1;

                // Update the margins
                relativeLayoutParams1.leftMargin += dx;
                relativeLayoutParams1.topMargin += dy;
                tv2.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams1);

                // Save where the user's finger was for the next ACTION_MOVE
                pressed_x1 = x;
                pressed_y1 = y;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.d("TAG","@@@@ TV2 ACTION_UP");
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

}